# How does css position impact element width/height?

Tags: css, height, width, position, element

How do the various options for css position (static, relative, absolute, fixed) impact the way percentage width/height is calculated?  This question may be too generic to provide a concrete answer, and it's possible that the answer is "the two are not directly related", but I'm having trouble understanding the impacts of css position on element size.

Links to related questions/answers are welcome.

Comment: yikes.  OT, but i got this message: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards when first attempting to post, and found it was only because i did not capitalize my sentences.  really??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you read [A List Apart's CSS Positioning article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/). It's the best article I've seen on the web.

Comment: useful article, thanks.  so can i assume that position does not impact width/height, with the exception of offsets in absolutely-positioned elements?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Positioning however can have a bad impact on the parent element (the [Great Collapse](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/) for example).