# CSS position relative : width not considered

Tags: html, css, css-position

I try to build [a pure CSS tree](https://jsfiddle.net/hkuwgpms/). I encountered a problem with horizontal lines between blocks (two blocks are at the same level). I isolated the problem in the following jsfiddles:

https://jsfiddle.net/8Lsv1ypd/3/

https://jsfiddle.net/8Lsv1ypd/4/

Html :

```
<span class="first">First</span>
<span class="second">Second</span>
```

CSS:

```
.first {
  background-color: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.second {
  background-color: #6f42c1;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.second::before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
  left: -30px;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0px;
  height: 26px;
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

When the CSS position (in .second::before) [is set to relative](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lsv1ypd/3/), the width (fixed in pixels) is not considered, only the vertical line is displayed and width is "forced by the browser" to 1 pixel.

When the CSS position (in .second::before) [is set to absolute](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lsv1ypd/4/), the width is not taken into account and the horizontal line is displayed, but the line is not joining the two block.

I already try many combinations of the following options:

- position : absolute / relative / static / fixed
- display : block / inline
- overflow : auto / visible;

I already look at the following questions :

- [CSS position relative without relative width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420264/css-position-relative-without-relative-width)
- [CSS relative div's width auto extend by absolute div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199111/css-relative-divs-width-auto-extend-by-absolute-div)
- [CSS relative, absolute positionings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604080/css-relative-absolute-positionings)
- [CSS Make the absolute child width independent from the relative parent width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568374/css-make-the-absolute-child-width-independent-from-the-relative-parent-width)
- [How does css position impact element width/height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455190/how-does-css-position-impact-element-width-height)
- [How to use CSS position(relative, absolute) with percentage (height, width) dimension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250226/how-to-use-css-positionrelative-absolute-with-percentage-height-width-dime)

And the following article :

https://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101

Comment: you need inline-block .. pseudo element are inline element by default ... when setting absolute they become block element but remain inline when relative

Comment: and for the second issue, position:absolute need a reference, so you need to add `position: relative;` to the span element to have left/top working like you want

Comment: I agree with @TemaniAfif, `display: inline-block` & `position: relative` are the way to go

Comment: Yeaah ... great proposal : https://jsfiddle.net/bhn4kso9/ but I can't get ride of the blank space before the text "Second".

Comment: Yes, `display:inline-block` will always take some space use `float:left;` instead `inline-block` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the CSS position (in .second::before) is set to relative, the width (fixed in pixels) is not considered, only the vertical line is displayed and width is "forced by the browser" to 1 pixel.

A pseudo element is an inline element by default, setting `position:relative` will not change this thus you cannot apply width and height to the element. Then the borwser is not forcing the width to `1px`, it's the border you have set that is equal to `1px`. The height also isn't working and the height of the element and the border is defined by the font property.

Increase the height and you will see that nothing will change:

```css
.first {
  background-color: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.second {
  background-color: #6f42c1;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.second::before {
  content: "";
  top: -13px;
  left: -30px;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="first">First</span>
<span class="second">Second</span>
```

Now increase the `font-size` and you will see some changes

```css
.first {
  background-color: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.second {
  background-color: #6f42c1;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.second::before {
  content: "";
  top: -13px;
  left: -30px;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0px;
  height: 600px;
  font-size:50px;
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="first">First</span>
<span class="second">Second</span>
```

---

> When the CSS position (in .second::before) is set to absolute, the width is not taken into account and the horizontal line is displayed, but the line is not joining the two block.

When adding `position:absolute` the element become a block level element thus you can know control its width and height and both are considered in your case but your element is positionned relatively to the viewport since there is no positionned ancestor. It's hidden because you set a negative left value so you cannot see the border you have set.

You need to make the span `position:relative` to make the pseudo element positionned relatively to the span:

```css
.first {
  background-color: #dc3545;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.second {
  background-color: #6f42c1;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

.second::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  left: -30px;
  border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0px;
  height: 26px;
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="first">First</span>
<span class="second">Second</span>
```

---

> 10.3.1 Inline, non-replaced elements
>
> The 'width' property **does not apply** <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-width)</sup>

---

> 10.6.1 Inline, non-replaced elements
>
> The 'height' property **does not apply**. The height of the content area should be **based on the font**, <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced)</sup>

---

> Floats, **absolutely positioned elements**, block containers (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) **establish new block formatting contexts for their contents**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)</sup>

---

> In the absolute positioning model, a box is explicitly offset with respect to **its containing block**
>
> If the element has `'position: absolute'`, the containing block is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute', 'relative' or 'fixed', ... If there is no such ancestor, the containing block is the **initial containing block**. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details)</sup>

Comment: Yeah ! Perfect and awesome answer. I still have some adjustments to perform, but the main core is there : https://jsfiddle.net/hkuwgpms/ Thank you very much.